# IDispatchOperationSelector question

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

i built a service with a custom operation selector, the selector simply looks at a specific element in the message body ( and ignores the action) to specify which method to call on a contract.

This works fine, and i can see that the server code is being invoked now, however the client throws an exception saying that the action of the request doesn't meet with action of response.

what extensibility point would help me to tweak the response action header, or can i do something at the client for it to accept the changed action ...

many thanks

Comment: It may be useful to provide more info about exception (type and stack trace); I can imagine e.g. some protocol channel like security playing a role here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting the OperationContractAttribute's ReplyAction="*" , so that the action of the message is set to nothing, so client wont get confused when i switch operations on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using adding an [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) implementation and change the action on the outgoing message in the [BeforeSendReply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.beforesendreply.aspx)() method. Depending on exactly what you're doing in your IDispatchOperationSelector, it may be possible to get rid of it and do everything inside the message inspector instead.